# Git Workflow, Nvie Branching Model Ahead and Behind

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-workflow

Following Nvie's git branching model, why do I end up with 'develop' and 'master' each 1 ahead and 1 behind the other after merging the same 'release' branch into both? If the same 'release' branch is merged into each, shouldn't master and develop agree?

```
x   84a628d      (origin/develop, develop) Merge branch 'release-v3.0.1' into develop
|\  
| | x   2e4d60b  (HEAD, v3.0.1, origin/master, master) Merge branch 'release-v3.0.1'
| | |\  
| | |/  
| |/|   
| x | 716ce96    (release-v3.0.1) Version 3.0.1
|/ /  
x | fe3b54d      Some more more code
x | 3683892      Some more code
x | 8c0b835      'develop' branch code
|/  
x   d051b54      (v3.0) Baseline merge. Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
```

$ git log origin/master ^origin/develop

```
commit 2e4d60b7d6760b4f6b2328ab06150b020b0d279f
Merge: d051b54 716ce96
Author: Todd 
Date:   Tue Mar 26 11:27:59 2013 -0400

Merge branch 'release-v3.0.1'
```

$ git log origin/develop ^origin/master

```
commit 84a628d96653ed196faa6387c8b208badf23aa75
Merge: fe3b54d 716ce96
Author: Todd 
Date:   Tue Mar 26 11:31:53 2013 -0400

Merge branch 'release-v3.0.1' into develop
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log origin/master ^origin/develop
```

This command displays all commits reachable from `origin/master` but not from `origin/develop`

```
git log origin/develop ^origin/master
```

This command displays all commits reachable from `origin/develop` but not from `origin/master`

The output from both these above commands seem to be consistent with the graph you've shown.

If you intend to find out the difference in the contents of the 2 branches, you should be using the `git diff` command instead.

```
git diff origin/master..origin/develop
```

If you want only the list of files which are different, you can use the `--name-status` option:

```
git diff --name-status origin/master..origin/develop
```

In git, a commit's SHA1 is calculated based on the parent commit's SHA1, the commit message, the timestamps, and lot of other such information. Although you've merged the same `release-v3.0.1` branch into both `master` and `develop`, you've done it as 2 independent merges at 2 different time instants. This would obviously not produce the same commit SHA1 for both.

What you should've done instead is one of the following:

**Option 1:**

```
git checkout master:
git merge release-v3.0.1

git checkout develop:
git merge master

git checkout master
# This would be a fast-forward merge
git merge develop
```

**Option 2:**

```
git checkout develop:
git merge release-v3.0.1

git checkout master:
git merge develop

git checkout develop
# This would be a fast-forward merge)
git merge master
```

This way you would end up with both `master` and `develop` branches pointing to the same commit.

You could get to the same state even now by merging either `master` into `develop` or the other way around, and doing a fast-forward merge on the other branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge develop

git checkout develop
# This would be a fast-forward merge
git merge master
```

Comment: Thanks Tuxdude! What's the point of merging master/develop and develop/master directly if you are trying to follow Nvie's branching model and provide a release branch for continuous work on the develop branch? ... [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: @Todd - The graph you've shown follows Nvie's branching model, but the commands you used to figure out the differences are incorrect. You should be using the `git diff develop..master` command instead to diff the contents of the 2 trees, rather than merely checking the commits using the `git log` command. The reason why I told you about merging develop and master directly, is to make both the branch pointers point to the same commit after a merge from release. How you maintain the branches is totally upto you ;)

Comment: Ahhh... 'diff' does report zero differences as I was expecting for my case! So... 'log' reports on the commits and 'diff' reports the absolute changes between entities (nodes, branches, versions, etc.)!! So it seems that the 'Branches' tab on GitHub is reporting the results of a 'log' and the commit deltas between merged branches. Unfortunately not what I expected and not clear for the uninitiated. Thank you Tuxdude! (sorry I don;t have the rep to up-vote your answer)